# How to use mempack from libgit2?

Tags: c, git, libgit2

There is a function `git_mempack_dump()` which puts some in-memory objects into buffer (from code comments):

> The contents of the packfile will be stored in the given buffer.
>   It is the caller's responsibility to ensure that the generated
>   packfile is available to the repository

But I can't find any subtle way to put buffer's content to the disk inside repository's default ODB - using libgit2 API.

Am I missing something or it's just unimplemented yet?

Comment: From the manpage: `The contents of the packfile will be stored in the given buffer.    It is the caller's responsibility to ensure that the generated  packfile is available to the repository (e.g. by writing it to disk, or doing something crazy like distributing it across   several copies of the repository over a network).`. So indeed, you have to care yourself about what to do with it. But it isn't particularly hard to write it to disk, is it?

Comment: @Ctx It breaks all the abstractions - I don't want to know how and where I should put pack inside current version of git repository. It's like compiler gives you a binary assembled sequence of some ELF section and tells you: put it somewhere and execute.

Comment: There are no subtle way because libgit2 doesn't know how the ODB backends you might be using actually work, hence it relies on you to make the call (ie. packfiles might not even make sense for some backends). Hence, you're supposed to know that executables go in $PATH / `.git/objects/pack`. An alternative would be to use the `packbuilder` API directly, which ought to give you more control over what it is you're trying to do while staying clear of the caveats of `memdump`.